# Gracenote Android - why does it need ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION?

Tags: gracenote

I noticed on the tutorial that in order to use the `Gracenote Android SDK` you need to enable the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. Why is this? I've also heard that apps implementing the `Gracenote SDK` have been delivering location-aware push adverts to their users. I can't find any explanation for either of these in the documentation.

Comment: The support page suggests using this SO tag to ask questions, so I was assuming that some Gracenote employees are watching this tag for support questions.

Comment: In fact I just looked at Gracenote's support forum, and they said they're migrating their entire support over to SO: https://developer.gracenote.com/notice-moving-stack-overflow

Comment: @323go: Please clarify why you have marked this post as off-topic

Answer (score 1):

ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is only needed for the MusicID Sample Application, and not the Gracenote SDK itself. Your app may not need that permission, and the SDK will work just fine.